# Windows Phone 8.1 gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How can I create a stackpanel in a gridview with various elements in the stackpanel responding to different click event?

The stackpanel will contain 2 appbarbutton and each appbarbutton has a textblock that increments based on the number of clicks...

```
        <GridView ItemsSource={Binding}>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <AppBarButton Icon="Like"
                          Name="like"
                          IsCompact="True"
                          Click="like_Click"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="numOfLike"
                       Text="{Binding No_Positive_Likes}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <AppBarButton Icon="Dislike"
                          Name="dislike"
                          IsCompact="True"
                          Click="dislike_Click"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="numOfDisLike"
                       Text="{Binding No_negative_Likes}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Tapped="loadQuestionAnswer_Click">
                        <TextBlock Name="question"
                       Text="What is my name"
                       FontSize="30"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="2013-12-10"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: Please add some sample code

Comment: Generally with DataTemplate, but it is unclear what exactly you want to achieve. AppBarButtons should belong on to the AppBar..

Comment: And what is the problem? You can get tapped Grid item in your event, using DataContext on the sender..

Comment: I want the three UI element (the appbarbutton and the textBox) to respond to different click events. the appbarbutton uses ObservableCollection at the back end so that the UI can update. But with the current code, it only works for all the elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have handled this same scenario using the BehaviorsSDK.This SDK makes life easy by adding the ability to call a function for an event. Just add a reference in your project to the BehaviorsSDK and then add a method to your item data class for each event. Here is an example:

```
ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items;

public class ItemModel
{
    public bool No_Positive_Likes ... 
    public bool No_Negative_Likes ...

    public void LikeButtonPressed()
    {
        ...
    }
    public void DislikeButtonPressed()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in your xamll:

```
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    ...

    <GridView ItemsSource={Binding}>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Like"
                            Name="like"
                            IsCompact="True">
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                                    <core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="LikeButtonPressed"/>
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </AppBarButton>
```