# Windows Phone 8.1 Two Column Gridview Within Pivot

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am having trouble displaying a two column gridview in a Windows Phone 8.1 application.

This is my intended result:
[image]

After reviewing [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804051/gridview-with-two-columns-win-phone-8-1) dealing with [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640422/windows-phone-8-1-gridview), I produced the following code:

```
 <Canvas>

    <Grid Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="93*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Pivot  Name="centerPivot" Margin="0,109,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Tapped="centerPivot_Tapped">
            <PivotItem Name="FindPivotItem" Margin="11,10,13,0.333">
                <PivotItem.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Name="FindTitle" FontSize="31" Text="Store Finds" Foreground="#FF878787" FontFamily="Global User Interface" />
                    </Grid>
                </PivotItem.Header>
                <!--<GridView 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 

                  ItemTemplate="{Binding ManyListingStyle}"

                  Grid.Row="1" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Height="450" Margin="0,0,-0.167,0" 
             />-->

                <GridView 

                Name="GridGridView"

                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                Grid.Row="4"
                IsSwipeEnabled="True" 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                >
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"
                                  MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"

                                  >

                            </WrapGrid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190" Height="240">
                                <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="193" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176" Margin="0,0,0,-8"/>
                                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="13,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Source="Assets/example.jpg"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,141,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Width="150" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,165,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding price}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFF9700" FontSize="16" Width="48"/>

                            </Grid>


                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">

                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <!--<Grid Margin="214,10,10,421">
                <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="209" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176"/>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="13,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Source="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,163,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding GetListTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Width="150"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,187,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding GetPrice}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFF9700" FontSize="16" Width="48"/>

            </Grid>-->
                    <!--</GridView.ItemTemplate>-->
                </GridView>

            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
        <Rectangle x:Name="ScreenDimRectangle" Fill="#FF555453" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="640" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Opacity="0.5"
               Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.ZIndex="9"/>


    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

This code, however, when bound to a list element with 8 objects, displays the following:
[image: Produced Layout]

This layout also  **does not scroll** .

After researching the around the web heavily, I believe I am quite stuck. I would think that the `WrapGrid` and `MaximumRowsOrColumns` settings should be what I am really after here, and their settings should (at least according to others) produce my intended result.

My Binding Code:

```
//Create new Fake Listings
        var listings = new List<Listing>();

        var fakelisting1 = new Listing();
        fakelisting1.title = "Brand new Product!";
        fakelisting1.price = "9.99";
        listings.Add(fakelisting1);

        var fakelisting2 = new Listing();
        fakelisting2.title = "Here is the new Product!";
        fakelisting2.price = "19.99";
        listings.Add(fakelisting2);

        var fakelisting3 = new Listing();
        fakelisting3.title = "Here is the new 2Product!";
        fakelisting3.price = "29.99";
        listings.Add(fakelisting3);

        var fakelisting4 = new Listing();
        fakelisting4.title = "Here is the new 3Product!";
        fakelisting4.price = "39.99";
        listings.Add(fakelisting4);

        var fakelisting5 = new Listing();
        fakelisting5.title = "Here is the new 4Product!";
        fakelisting5.price = "49.99";
        listings.Add(fakelisting5);

        var fakelisting6 = new Listing();
        fakelisting6.title = "Here is the new 5Product!";
        fakelisting6.price = "59.99";
        listings.Add(fakelisting6);

        var fakelisting7 = new Listing();
        fakelisting7.title = "Here is the new 6Product!";
        fakelisting7.price = "49.99";
        listings.Add(fakelisting7);

        var fakelisting8 = new Listing();
        fakelisting8.title = "Here is the new 7Product!";
        fakelisting8.price = "49.99";
        listings.Add(fakelisting8);

        GridGridView.DataContext = listings;
```

Why am I not seeing that result?

Comment: delete width="378" and it will work

Comment: Deleting it did not seem to change much. UI looks exactly the same and still does not scroll.

Comment: okay i will try somethings and if anything works let you know

Comment: you just want two column in the grid?

Comment: Yea, two columns with a custom rectangle data template set up in each. Identical to what you see in the first image.

Comment: @JcKelley I don't get it, I tried your code with width deleted it works fine.. scroll works fine too. here's [screenshot](http://imgur.com/tS8hggV) don't mind the number orders.

Comment: Does it matter if my gridview is within a pivot? I will post my back-end code as well. Maybe it has to do with how I am binding it?

Comment: By taking it out of the pivot I am able to get it to render correctly horizontally (1,2,3,4) in two columns, but it still does not scroll.

Comment: change `GridGridView.DataContext = listings;` to `GridGridView.ItemsSource = listings;`

Comment: as for making it two column check if pivot has width more than 400(i think this width will be enough)

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect my entire page layout now to give you a better picture. Changing `DataContext` to `ItemSource` didn't do anything.

The primary problem when the gridview is within the pivot is that it renders the datetemplate vertically instead of horizontally and it does not scroll (it is swipable and animates, but does not allow you to scroll down any further)

Comment: Setting `Orientation="Horizontal"` will change your items order. Also, set Height to the GridGridView

Comment: Setting orientation to Horizontal shows me a single column versus two columns. Set what "height" to the GridGridview?

Answer (score 1):

What I've done:

- when you want your items in [*WrapGrid* be placed horizontally first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid.aspx), use `Orientation=Horizontal`,
- I've changed the item's grid width to 180, when it was 190 then items were placed vertically, as on my screen the width was too small,
- I've changed *MaximumRowsOrColumns* to 2 as you want two items horizontally,
- I've removed the *ScrollViewer* information - it's being applied automatically by *GridView*.
- I've removed *Canvas*, so the *GridView* knows how much place it has.

The code look like this:

```xml
<Grid Margin="0,150,0,0" Tapped="Grid_Tapped" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="93*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Pivot Name="centerPivot" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Tapped="centerPivot_Tapped">
        <PivotItem Name="FindPivotItem" Margin="11,10,13,0.333">
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Name="FindTitle" FontSize="31" Text="Store Finds" Foreground="#FF878787" FontFamily="Global User Interface" />
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem.Header>

            <GridView Name="GridGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Height="240">
                            <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="193" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176" Margin="0,0,0,-8"/>
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="13,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Source="Assets/example.jpg"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,141,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Width="150" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,165,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding price}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFF9700" FontSize="16" Width="48"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

And the result:

[image: Items]

Comment: This answer does not render the items horizontally. Instead, it renders them vertically first (so that only 1,2,4,5 are showing when 6 elements are rendered. You have to scroll to see 3,6). Take a look at my visual in the above question for more information on what I am looking for.

Comment: @JcKelley I've rebuild the answer litte - the GridView's ScrollViewer now is used and items are laced horizontally. You have to play a little with item's grid width and margin to position elements correctly.